# passing cell index between uicollectioncontroller and viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have the main view controller that is UICollectionViewController where I declare:

```
var cellIndex: Int = 0
```

then I assign a value to this variable in didSelectItemAtIndexPath method

```
cellIndex = indexPath.item+1
```

then I send it to the second view controller via prepareForSegue method

```
destination.cellIndexToUse = self.cellIndex
```

in my second view controller (that is destination) I declare

```
var cellIndexToUse: Int = 0
```

and then in viewDidLoad I call a function that assigns an empty array the value of the correct array of images to show depending on what cell has been tapped, this function is  ...

```
func assignArrays () { 
if cellIndexToUse == 0 {objectsImages = imagesA}
if cellIndexToUse == 1
{objectImages = imagesB}
if cellIndexToUse == 2 
{objectImages = imagesC}
if cellIndexToUse == 3
{objectImages = imagesD}
```

my problem is:
when i click the cells all the images are show correctly, but then if I click for the second time all the cells, the first cell shows no images, all the rest are perfectly OK.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling the function too early. `viewDidLoad` occurs before the assignment of `cellIndexToUse`.

Try setting up the images in `viewWillAppear` instead.

Comment: it didn't help... thus I'm making a mistake to retrieve the indexPath... have to study more how to do that

Comment: maybe I am making a mistake in this line: "cellIndex=indexPath.item" as it doesn't get me the correct int

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a probable cause. I assumed that the other mechanics work as expected. Besides, it is not a very good idea to work with index paths in this way, but that's another problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem and it works perfectly fine. I will write an answer here in case someone needs it:

I didn't need `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` at all, so I deleted it, but I corrected `prepareForSegue` method:

```
if (segue.identified == "mySegueIdentifier") {
  let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! MyNextViewController
  destination.cellIndexToUse = (myCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.first?.item)!}
```